# KafkaSpout (Storm) Doesn't apear in Kafka Manager

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, kafka-consumer-api

I am using KafkaSpout with ZkHosts configuration as described [here](http://storm.apache.org/documentation/storm-kafka.html).

This is how SpoutConfig is initialized :

```
 SpoutConfig kafkaConfig = new SpoutConfig(kafkaBrokerHosts, kafkaTopic,
            "/consumers" , topologyName);
```

The Spout works well, it is recieving the events being sent to Kafka.

How can i set it, so Storm will aprear as a consumer in Kafka Manager ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storm-kafka writes its consumer information in different location and different format(JSON) in zookeeper rather than traiditional kafka way of doing it. You have to see such information manually in zookeeper. Any kafka monitoring tool would not work for your purpose.